# How to create a column which counts occurrences within another column and does not aggregate rows in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to count the occurrences of specific elements within a column and add the count of occurrences as an additional column without removing rows.

I have tried

```py
df['counts']=df.no_.value_counts()

df['counts']=df.groupby(no_).count()

O21['count']=df.groupby('no_').transform('count')
```

This is what I have:

```
id|no| 
---------
1 |  1  | 
2 |  3  |  
3 |  3  | 
4 |  4  |  
5 |  2  |
```

Ideally, I would like it to look like this

```
id|no_  |count(no_)| 
---------------
1 |  1  |   1 |  
2 |  3  |   2 |
3 |  3  |   2 | 
4 |  4  |   1 |  
5 |  2  |   1 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, need specify column after `groupby`:

```
df['count'] = df.groupby('no_')['no_'].transform('count')
```

Or use `map`:

```
df['counts']= df.no_.map(df.no_.value_counts())

print (df)
   id  no_  counts
0   1    1       1
1   2    3       2
2   3    3       2
3   4    4       1
4   5    2       1
```